# how to write computed setters in class-based components in vuejs

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have below code for a computed property.

```
computed: {
  filterText: {
    get() {
      return this.filter; // it's a vuex state
    },
    set(value) {
      this.setFilter(value); // it's a vuex action
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I want to write it in class-based components. I think `getter` should be like this, but how to write `setter`?

```
get filterText() {
  return this.filter
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Class based components use `get` and `set` for computed properties:

```
get filterText() {
  return this.filter
}

set filterText(value) {
  this.filter = value
}
```

A single file component written in TypeScript would be structured like:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

  @Component
  export default class MyClass extends Vue {
    private filter: string = ''

    public get filterText(): string {
      return this.filter
    }

    public set filterText(filter: string) {
      this.filter = filter
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How do I call the set method?

Comment: @farahm `this.filterText = value`

Comment: @farahm Actually, it should already work with     <component v-model="filterText"/>