# Computed getter/setter for vue-models (therefore, "props") in vue-class-component syntax

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-class-components, vue-property-decorator

In thread  [Which limitations v-model has in Vue 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63028861/which-limitations-v-model-has-in-vue-2-x), I learned how to link parent and child components `v-model`. The [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63029271/4818123) is:

```js
--- ParentTemplate:
<Child v-model="formData"></Child>

-- ChildTemplate:
<input v-model="localValue">

-- ChildScript:
computed: {
    localValue: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(localValue) {
        this.$emit('input', localValue);
      },
    },
  },
```

Unfortunately, I could not re-write it to [vue-class-component](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/class-component.html#computed-properties) syntax. Below code neither works nor should work:

```js
export default class TextEditor extends Vue {

  @Prop({ type: String, required: true }) private readonly value!: string;


  private get localValue(): string {
    return this.value;
  }

  private set localValue(newValue: string) {
    this.$emit("input", newValue);
  }
}
```

The answer to question [how to write computed setters in class-based components in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53880717/how-to-write-computed-setters-in-class-based-components-in-vuejs) is not applicable to vue component properties because properties are readonly. So I can't write `this.value = newValue`.

### Problem with straight `value` usage##

```html
<EditorImplementation 
  :value="value" 
  @input="(value) => { onInput(value) }" 
/>
```

```js
@Component({
  components {
    EditorImplementation: CK_Editor.component
  }
})
export default class TextEditor extends Vue {

  @Prop({ type: String, required: true }) private readonly value!: string;


  @Emit("input")
  private onInput(value: string): void {
    console.log("checkpoint");
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}
```

Assume that initially value is empty string.

1. Input "f"
2. Log will be `"checkpoint" ""`
3. Input "a"
4. Log will be `"checkpoint" "f"`
5. Input "d"
6. Log will be `"checkpoint" "fa"`

And so on.

Comment: I don't think this is the best way to go about it. You shouldn't mutate props directly. Why can't you just put the `value` props directly in your template. Something like

`<input :value="value">`

Comment: @Tony, thank you for the answer. With `EditorImplementation(:value="value" @input="(value) => { onInput(value) }")`, in `@Emit("input") private onInput(value: string): void { console.log(this.value); }` I always get output with previous `value`, not actual. E. g. on first input, `value` is still empty string. Is it normal?

Comment: Hi, please edit the post and add this function for better readability.

Comment: @Tony, Roger that, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, it seems like you get an input value from the parent, and then you change the value, and emit that value back to the parent. That seems like an anti-pattern.

Please try this

Your *EditorImplementation* component will be something like

```js
 <input
  ....
  :value="value"
  @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
 />
 
@Prop({default: ''}) readonly value!: string
```

#### And then

```js
<EditorImplementation 
  v-model="localValue"
  @input="(value) => { onInput(value) }" 
/>
```

and you import it into the Text Editor file like you have done

```js
@Component({
  components {
    EditorImplementation: CK_Editor.component
  }
})
export default class TextEditor extends Vue {
  private localValue = '';

  @Emit("input")
  private onInput(value: string): void {
 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, the `value` will not change inside `TextEditor` with `localValue`, isn't it? Is somewhere in documentation explained about this?

Comment: With `localValue`, you can change the value of the text input using v-model (this ensures two way binding). You can see more [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) about how to use v-model on custom components (which is what the `EditorImplementation` component is. [This](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) shows how v-model is used with html elements.

Comment: Regarding props change, you can technically change the props from the child component, but the value(changed in the child component) will be over-ridden if the value changes from the parent component and that's why it's discouraged. In this case, it seems like you want to emit a value from the child component to the parent component. Using v-model, you can change the value of the text input in the child component, and emit the value to the parent component without worrying about over-ridden values.

Comment: O'K, thank you for the explanations! I accepted your great answer.